# How to install ubuntu server 22.04 update via flasdisk no internet

Tags: drivers, server

I'm new in linux and just installed Ubuntu Server and it hasn't been updated. both drivers and tools are needed and there is no internet around here. The question is

1. How to update via flash drive after successfully downloading the installation package
2. If number 1 is successful, how to connect to WiFi if everything is installed. Maybe in the future I will borrow a wifi modem device or something like that so that it can be easy in the update process.

my wifi chipset is broadcom, qualcom

please i hope you can pardon me step by step.

Comment: This is a difficult task as you basically need to mirror the whole package repos of Ubuntu to ensure you get all packages you need for an update. Not sure about the size, but we talk about 10.000+ packages.
Plus you would need to do it frequently, as basically packages updates are there every day.
On the other hand: if the server is in an isolated network, the question is if updates are really mandatory like for a server connected "to the wild".

Comment: +1 for: 'On the other hand: if the server is in an isolated network, the question is if updates are really mandatory like for a server connected "to the wild"'